# Shoretel Upgrade Path

Tags: windows-server-2003, pbx, shoretel

I currently have a Shoretel Server running Server 2003 x32 as a virtual machine paired with a ShoreGear 90 switch and another unused switch of the same model being reserved for manual failover. I am getting the software mailed to me from my partner, but with limited support since the server is in a relatively remote area. I am tempted to upgrade the OS at the same time as performing the upgrade, but want to know if there are any horror stories or advice I should know about before diving in.

I'm upgrading from Shoretel 9.2 Build. I will be upgrading first to version 10.1 then finally to 11.1. The system has been bullet proof since it was installed and we are upgrading mainly to get a client that is a little more modern.

My question boils down to: Should I even bother with an OS upgrade or even possibly a fresh install of Windows with an install of Shoretel 11.1 and just transfer the configuration?

Should I just stay with Server 2003 since it is supported in my target version of Shoretel and the upgrade will be more than enough to keep me busy as a novice?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Windows 2003 has been been running it great, but the OS is getting old and won't be supported much longer. I am tempted to "bite the bullet" and put it on a newer OS like 2008 that will be capable of running it, and future versions or Shoretel, for the next 5 to 10 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Server 2003 has left mainstream support (back in 2010) and will end extended support in 2015.

I would definitely recommend migrating to at least Windows 2008 if not Windows Server 2012  depending on if the version of Shoretel you want to migrate to supports it and if there is nothing else preventing you from doing so (this being a domain controller, or something odd like that).

Realize as well your upgrade paths.  You can't simply upgrade the 2003 VM to 2008 R2 (64 bit OS).  Check with MS Technet upgrade paths to make sure you are good.